# Magnitude of Type I error inflation related to error noise after model selection

Tags: regression, inference, feature-selection, stepwise-regression, type-i-and-ii-errors

I am investigating Type I error inflation for the one-sided test $$H_0:\beta_2=0$$ after one step of forward stepwise regression for the following model: $$Y=X_1+\beta_2X_2+\epsilon$$ where $\epsilon \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ assuming $\sigma$ is known. So when calculating the p-value, I am using the basic procedure for linear regression assuming a known standard deviation. So the distribution of $\hat{\beta_2}$ follows $N(\beta_2, \sigma^2 (X^TX)^{-1})$. I performed a simulation by fixing the sample size and varying $\sigma$. I performed one step of forward stepwise selection and calculated the type I error for the one sided test mentioned (thus, I only looked at the times when the model with the second predictor was selected under the null).

I noticed that when the signal ($\sigma$) decreased that the Type I error actually increased. I am not sure if this should be the case or not. Is this true and if so is there an intuitive explanation for it?

Comment: In samples where the error variance is underestimated, the standard error of the estimated $\beta$ parameter will be similarly underestimated, leading to inflated t-statistics.